# How do you invoke a TFS Build from another TFS Build?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Basically, I have 2 build definitions, one builds and deploys some database projects, and the other builds and deploys a website.

What I would like to do is be able to build/deploy the databases, and if that doesn't have any errors, build and deploy the web app.

The idea being that if database deploy fails for some reason, I can restore the database from a backup and fix the issue before I deploy the web app. (Leaving the previous version of the app working)

Any info on how to invoke my database build definition, from within my web app build def would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the Community [TFS Build Extensions](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/), it contains the Queue Build custom activity which you use (or) you can call TFSBuild Commandline tool by using Invoke Process Activity.